# Visual Studio 2015 says the 'cast is redundant'. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have an image with width 888px and height 592px, with aspect ratio of width:height as 3:2.

The following produces a wrong value of 1, because of integer calculation/truncation as BitmapDecoder.PixelWidth and BitmapDecoder.PixelHeight are both `uint` (unsigned integer), and `decoder` below being a BitmapDecoder object.

`double aspectRatio = decoder.PixelWidth / decoder.PixelHeight;`

The following gives the expected correct value of 1.5, but Visual Studio says 'Cast is redundant', but why?

`double aspectRatio = (double)decoder.PixelWidth / (double)decoder.PixelHeight;`

Comment: you need just one (double) cast - double / int = double. Or int / double = double.

Comment: The result will always be a double if you divide a double with any numeric type.

Comment: `double aspectRatio = static_cast<double>(decoder.PixelWidth) / decoder.PixelHeight;` should be sufficient to make the compiler use `PixelHeight` as a double.

Comment: To be absolutely accurate, I wish Visual Studio left the first cast alone as necessary and only rendered the second cast as redundant. In that sense Visual Studio is a [tiny] bit misleading but can be explained (or argued) why.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You only need to cast *one* of the uints to double to force the floating point arithmetic so either:

```
double aspectRatio = decoder.PixelWidth / (double)decoder.PixelHeight;
```

or:

```
double aspectRatio = (double)decoder.PixelWidth / decoder.PixelHeight;
```

Personally, I'd go with the latter, but it is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Get it! One cast would have been enough but Visual Studio put me off the track. I wish Visual Studio left alone the first cast and only rendered the second cast as unnecessary to be absolutely accurate. In that sense Visual Studio is a bit misleading but can be explained why.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement @ChrisF's answer, you can see this nicely in the IL code, where a single cast to `double` will yield a conversion for both values:

```
IL_0013:  stloc.0     // decoder
IL_0014:  ldloc.0     // decoder
IL_0015:  callvirt    UserQuery+Decoder.get_PixelHeight
IL_001A:  conv.r.un   // convert uint to float32
IL_001B:  conv.r8     // convert to float64 (double)
IL_001C:  ldloc.0     // decoder
IL_001D:  callvirt    UserQuery+Decoder.get_PixelWidth
IL_0022:  conv.r.un   // convert uint to float32
IL_0023:  conv.r8     // convert to float64 (double)
```